# Why is data validation not working with entire list of times?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, time, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a list of 96 times in 15 minute intervals that I'm trying to use for data validation. It turns out that it works only up to a certain point. When selecting times from 00:00 to 18:30 it works fine. When selecting times from 18:45 to 23:45 it throws an error.

> The data that you entered in cell B1 violates the data validation
> rules set on this cell.

I made a test file to see if the same thing would happen if I used a different type of data, but when using a lists of numbers or text with the same amount of items it seems to work without issues.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ClBhZk6fysOq0wqIrE5IxJgPMs_A05gJsN_kEiXoFGI/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone know the reason why it doesn't work with the list of times? More importantly, does anyone know a way I could get it to work?

Edit:
The steps provided by player0 worked to fix it in my test file linked above, but didn't make a difference in the real file I'm working on. Here's a copy of the real file which exhibits the same problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cOMB0BpzSBR7ZM7fJQQfhA56fniKTBJb-3TePUky6gM/edit?usp=sharing

Please try setting a time of greater than 18:30 in a couple of cells. I keep getting the same errors.

I suppose a workaround could be to not reject input on invalid data, but I feel this should just work with rejecting it and would like to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

formatting. select columns A & B and force Time (or Plain text):

[image]

Comment: When I force both columns to time, it is initially possible to set the cell within the entire range, but then afterwards when I try to change it again, the same limitation of not being able to select anything higher than 18:30 applies again. Then I have to reselect both columns and set them to time again (keeping the column selected from before and setting to time doesn't seem to work, I have to select something else first, then reselect the column and then set to time), then again it works only once.

Comment: @Rainier I'm testing it in your sheet and it works for me every time, even multiple times in a row. did you try Plain text instead of Time? that works for me too

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. It does work for me as well in that test file, but in the actual sheet I was working on it refuses to work. I've edited the post to add a copy of the actual file which exhibits the same problem. Setting the data type to text isn't an option, since I have to do calculations with the times.

Comment: Seems that setting to plain text works after all. Who would have thought!